# C++ question. about container and instance of class

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, stl, containers

```
A* a = new A(x,y);
set<A> aset;
aSet.insert(a);
```

I did this. Got an error. How should I fix it?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please please please provide more context (like error messages) than "I did this, got an error, fix it"

Comment: It might help people to know how to begin to respond to this if you actually posted the exact error message. "An error" could be anything from "compiler spat out an error message" to "Guy from the electric company banged on the door and angrily insisted I stop the program because it was draining the grid."

Comment: sorry, my bad. I ll do it next time.

Comment: Do it this time.  Edit your post with the relevant details.

Answer (score 7):

aset is a set of A, not of pointers to A. So either

```
set<A*> aset;
```

or

```
aset.insert(*a);
```

but don't think the later makes too much sense.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the former makes too much sense. Collections of pointers are an advanced topic, they give you a whole extra realm of ways to get it wrong. For one thing, your set will be ordered and de-duplicated by the *address* of the objects rather than by their `<` operator. Which is fine if that's what you want, but it's probably not what you want. I also see distressingly few calls to `delete` in the questioner's code - how is this set going to be cleaned up? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to insert a pointer to an `A` into your set, but the set is declared as taking `A`s directly.

You must either change your set to store pointers:

```
A* a = new A(x,y);
set<A*> aset;
aSet.insert(a);
```

or create an instance, rather than a pointer to an instance:

```
A a = A(x,y);
set<A> aset;
aSet.insert(a);
```